# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "как" в данном предложении

Tags: запятые, как

Возник спор: в предложении — "Не знаете, как установить дверную ручку?" — нужна, или нет, запятая. Есть два мнения.

"Не знаете" — это глагол, в предложении является подлежащим. "Установить" — глагол-сказуемое. Между подлежащим и сказуемым запятая не ставится.

Или это определённо-личное предложение со сложноподчинённой изъяснительной частью. 2-я часть предложения безличная, где нет и не может быть подлежащего, а сказуемое выражено инфинитивом. Поэтому запятая нужна.

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти истину! Спасибо!

Comment: "Как" в данном случае не союз, а союзное слово.

Answer (score 4):

***Не знаете, как установить дверную ручку?***

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным, запятая ставится перед союзным словом "как".

**Главное предложение**: односоставное определенно-личное, ***не знаете*** ― сказуемое.

В таких предложениях подлежащее отсутствует, а субъект действия **определяется по лицу глагола** (здесь обращение ко второму лицу: (вы) не знаете.

**Придаточное предложение:** односоставное безличное (инфинитивное). В качестве сказуемого используется инфинитив ***установит***ь. ***Как*** ― союзное слово (= каким образом).

В таких предложениях также нет подлежащего, а субъект действия  устанавливается **по ситуации**: как (мне)  установить. Предполагаемый субъект действия в форме дополнения (Д.п.).

Answer (score 3):

Это сложноподчинённое предложение. Главное ("не знаете") – неполное, определенно-личное, главный член в котором является сказуемым, а не подлежащим, потому что подлежащее ("вы") опущено. Придаточное – "как установить дверную ручку". Запятая отделяет придаточное от главного.

Comment: Только не неполное, а односоставное

Comment: @Людмила, почему его нельзя назвать неполным?

Comment: Потому что неполное двусоставное - двусоставное с пропуском одного из членов, который восстанавливается из контекста, а односоставное не требует восстановления второго главного члена, он не нужен, указание на деятеля содержится в форме сказуемого, как в нашем случае. Не знаете - указание на то, что деятель - собеседник или обобщённое лицо. Здесь ничего не пропущено.

Comment: Правда, некоторые учёные относят односоставные к неполным, но там другая классификация, а мы вроде бы договаривались придерживаться общепринятых терминов.

Comment: Хм... Двусоставное с пропуском одного из членов. Я бы считал, что это и есть наше предложение - "[Вы] не знаете..." А односоставные - это такие, в которых второй главный член невозможен. Ведь "опущен" и "невозможен" - разные вещи? Ну ладно, вероятно, я путаюсь в терминологии.

Comment: Невозможен только в безличном односоставном, потому что действие происходит само, без деятеля.